# Ksoap and HttpTransport Seand AndroidHttpTransport Method Call

Tags: java, android, .net, web-services, ksoap2

In this example code, I have a reference to **ksoap2-android-assembly-2.6.3-jar-with-dependencies**
its incredible when do I arrive to the line `hts.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);` in debug mode; the application code ended with an error message into the Log Cat message error is :

```
-- 04-28 23:24:03.454: W/ActivityManager(80): Launch timeout has expired, giving up wake lock!
-- 04-28 23:23:38.667: W/ActivityManager(80): Activity idle timeout for ActivityRecord{407c0c10 yservices.screens/.MyservicesActivity}
```

My source code in the create event:

```
TextView tv = new TextView(this);
setContentView(tv);

SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);

SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
envelope.dotNet = true;
AndroidHttpTransport hts = new AndroidHttpTransport(URL);
try {

    hts.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);

    SoapPrimitive response = (SoapPrimitive)envelope.getResponse();
    // Log.i("myApp", response.toString());

    //tv.setText(weight+" "+fromUnit+" equal "+response.toString()+ " "+toUnit);
    tv.setText("Ok");

} catch(Exception e) {
    //e.getLocalizedMessage();
    tv.setText(e.getMessage());
}
```

I hope can you help me. My OS Version is Windows 7 64 Bit, Eclipse Indigo and JDK 1.6
if you need other information, write me.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My Error Was because the ksoap2 need has reference in a folder named libs and not into a builder path eclipse, last android version to windows 7 x64 has problem with last version ksoap2

Answer (score 0):

That **warning** means that your application is continually running. But I think that is not what you want so you should use an [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html)

Comment: when i call the method *hts.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);* i get this message ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread$ActivityClientRecord, Intent) line: 1813 and a button with description Source Not Found